# How do to add extra variables to sip register response header in freeswitch

Tags: header, response, freeswitch

I want to add account balance information to sip response message after successful registration.

The [documentation](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Sofia.conf.xml#Parameters) suggest to use

```
 <!--extra sip params to send in the contact-->
<param name="contact-params" value="tport=tcp"/>
```

I have added this to default.xml, sofia.conf.xml with no luck

Another suggestion from the [documentation](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Sofia-SIP#Adding_Custom_Headers)
   says to use

```
<action application="set"><![CDATA[sip_h_P-Charge-Info=<sip:${caller_id_number}@${domain_name}>;npi=0;noa=3]]></action>
```

But I ma not sure where to add this in my sip profile.

Answer (score 1):

[**Adding Response Headers**](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Sofia-SIP)

There are three types of response header prefixes that can be set:

**Response header**

sip_rh_

**Provisional response header**

sip_ph_

**Bye response header**

sip_bye_h_

Each prefix will exclusively add headers for their given types of requests - there is no "global" response header prefix that will add a header to all response messages.

For example:

`<action application="set" data="sip_rh_X-Reason=Destination Number Not in Footprint"/>
<action application="set" data="sip_bye_h_X-Accounting=Some Accounting Data"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You would add this

```
<action application="set"><![CDATA[sip_h_P-Charge-Info=<sip:${caller_id_number}@${domain_name}>;npi=0;noa=3]]></action>
```

to your dialplan, not the sip profile.